# Uploading images using php, but without page refresh

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, image-uploading

So generally, i don't have a problem (yet), but I need advice. I want't to make a page where a user can upload his/hers image. But the upload should not refresh the page as the other data that a user enters will get lost. I know there is a bunch of ajax and php uploader posts, but here's the thing. Using XMLHttpRequest 2 isn't supported in older browsers. I would like at least IE9 to be supported. I also know there is an iframe solution. But using iframe's today sounds to me like driving Mr.Beans Mini when you have a new BMW in the garage (no offense). So can anyone give me advice on what should I do? Which way should I go?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there is no real solution to `ajax upload`. All the codes I've seen are alternatives with `iframes`, so I'm afraid you'll need to do it that way...

Comment: Check this url http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

Comment: I use `swf_upload` plug-in several times in my control panels. It works clearly. I know flash technologies are not acceptted these days. But there are no more choise. You can use iframe or flash technologies as I know.

Comment: @Madurai Citizen I visited the page and found this "Currently file uploads work only in Firefox and Chrome". i need it to work in at least IE9

Comment: Uploadify might suit your needs. http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: @YasinYörük I wantto avoid flash because I would like the page to work on tablets

Comment: @DavidJones sorry that doesn't work for me

Comment: What I have done is built my own uploader where the image is read and displayed to the user using the file reader API, then the file is uploaded to the server when the user submits the form. You could used the formData object to send the $_FILES via AJAX. This will not work in older browsers so we fall back to uploadify if the file reader API is not available. This way the uploader works on IE8+ and tablets, as well as modern browsers

Comment: i found this tutorial, it's the easiest i could find and i think i'm gonna work from that http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best way to do things, infact I am looking for a faster way to do this, but here is something I have coded myself that will upload the image data to the database and also automatically change your profile photo without refresh.

First the HTML, CSS and Javascript/JQuery for the client side.

```js
//NOTE: this code is jquery, go to JQuery.com and find the download then link it in a script tag

$("#activateFile").on('click', function(){
   $("#fileBrowser").click();
  });

//if you want a finish edit button then use this otherwise put this code in the fileBrowser change event handler below KEEP THE readURL(this) OR IT WON'T WORK!

$("#finishEdit").on('click', function(){
  
    var imgData = document.getElementById('image').src;
  
   //imageData is the variable you use $_POST to get the data in php
   $.post('phpscriptname.php', {imageData:imgData}, function(data){ 
     
        //recieve information back from php through the echo function(not required)
     
     });
  });


$("#fileBrowser").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
  });

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function (e) {
   $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result)
    };
     
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
#fileBrowser{
  display: none;
  }

#image{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever your title is</title>
   </head>
  <body>
    
    <img id="image" src="somesource.png" alt="somesource"/>
    <!-- NOTE: you can use php to input the users current image in the source attribute -->
    <br/>
    <br/>
    
    <!-- position and style these however you like -->
    
    <input type="file" id="fileBrowser"> <!-- this is display none in css -->
    <button id="activateFile">Choose files</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="finishEdit">Done</button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I will I show the server side with the database

```
require("yourconnectiontodatabase.php"); //create a connection to your db.

$imgData = $_POST['imageData']; //the same variable we gave it in the jquery $.post method.

//The bad part now is because we are using data straight from the input I don't think it's possible to know if the content type of the file is an image. This is a security flaw as people could try upload .exe files however, I do know the imagedata we get in javascript contains the filetype it is so you could check in javascript if it's an image type like if it's png or jpeg.

//NOTE: when looking for types in images use image/type for example image/png

//upload image to database

$updateprofile = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET profileimage='$imgData' ");
```

Answer (score -1):

create a connection file conn.php

```
<?php
$dbhost ='localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'test';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('could not connect database');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('could not select database');
?>
```

create a image upload page with index.php

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1'; 
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#photoimg').on('change', function() { 
            $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                target: '#preview'
            }).submit();
        });
    }); 
</script>

<style>

body
{
font-family:arial;
}
.preview
{
width:200px;
border:solid 1px #dedede;
padding:10px;
}
#preview
{
color:#cc0000;
font-size:12px
}

</style>
<body>
<div style="width:600px">

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

create a image upload php script ajaxupload.php

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1';
$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
try {
        if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
            if($_FILES) {
                $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
                $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
                if(strlen($name)) {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
                        if($size<(1024*1024)) {
                            $actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
                                echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview'>";
                            } else {
                                throw new Exception("fiald to upload image");
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception("Image file size max 1 MB");
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception("Invalid file format..");
                    }
                } else {
                 throw new Exception("Please select image..!");
                }
            } else {
             throw new Exception("Please select image..!");
            }
        } 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```